# Check if entry exists in MongoDB using Python Flask

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection of "rooms" which contains a collection of "users." I am trying to search the "rooms" collection to see if a username already exists, and if it does, update the "user_ip" field. The collection looks like:

```
{
    '_id': ObjectId('59eea13a2728d50a5edefe0z'), 
    'name': 'RH-0', 
    'room_key': 'test123', 
    'users': 
        [{'username': 'Pablo', 'user_ip': '127.0.0.1', 'user_port':0}, 
         {'username': 'Franco', 'user_ip': '127.0.0.1', 'user_port':1}, 
         {'username': 'Valeri', 'user_ip': '127.0.0.1', 'user_port':2}, 
         {'username': 'Sarah', 'user_ip': '127.0.0.1', 'user_port':3}
        ], 
    'workshop_unit': 'wsu0'
}
```

My current solution attempts to use the roomname and username, but I would prefer to use just the "username" to search.

```
def user_exists(roomname, username):
if db.rooms.find({"name": roomname},{'username': username}).count() > 0:
    return 1
else:
    return 0
```

**Note: The username will be a unique one throughout all the collections.

Comment: You are trying to find two dictionaries, try merging them and you should see the result.

Comment: I have tried doing `if db.rooms.find({'username': username}).count() > 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0` but it does not provide the correct results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following Mongo shell code will do the job:

```
db.yourColl.update(
    { "users.username": "Valeri" },
    {
        "$set": { "users.$.user_ip": "1.1.0.0" }
    }
)
```

I'm pretty sure you can easily adapt this to your code.

Comment: I adapted this to work with my "user_exists" function! Thank you!

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer if it solved your issue?